# Understanding working of `div` and `span` elements as children in Descendant selectors

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
li p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<li>
  <div>
    <p>
       Usual text.
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

The *Usual text* gets a yellow background as expected. Now if I put a block-level element say `<div>` or `<h2>` inside the `<p>` tags something unusual happens. The content between the block-level elements and *after block-level elements* which is still inside the `<p>` tags don't get yellow background. E.g. consider the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
li p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<li>
  <div>
    <p>
       Usual text<div>Text Inside Div</div> After div but inside p.
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem doesn't appear if i use some inline-element like `<span>` or `<a>` inside `<p>` tags.

> - Why is this behavior shown by only block-level elements?

Comment: You wouldn't put a DIV right in the middle of a text block.  That is exactly what SPANs are for.

Comment: `<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I am just trying to put a _block-level_ element inside `<p>` tags. You can use `<h1>` instead.

Comment: No, actually, you can't.  It's invalid.  Plus, you will have line breaks where you don't want them.

Comment: As @durbnpoisn explains, you _cannot_ put a block-level element inside `<p>...</p>`. You can try, but the markup will no longer be valid.

Comment: I got it. If I use `<article>` instead of `<div>`, delete `<li>` and replace `<p>` with `<div>` then everything goes ok. I guess the unexpected behaviour was because of invalid html.

Comment: Do I delete the question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CSS. It is a purely HTML issue.

Div elements are not allowed inside P elements.

Additionally, the end tag for the P element is optional and the end of the paragraph will be implied by the Div start tag (rendering the P end tag an orphan).

Comment: Yes. You are right. I've found many posts explaining this issue. It seems like flow content can't be put inside phrasing content.

Comment: There was an answer on which there was a comment saying "Background-color" property isn't inherited without setting it explicitly. Then how how does the nested elements still get that background color?

Comment: @user31782 – Because their default background colour is `transparent` (usually; `input`s are an obvious exception).

Comment: Right. I just set another back-color for nested elements and they got that color. Thanks for explaining.